# Is there a way to print a web page via a SWF?

Tags: flash, printing

In my web app, I would like to print a web page via a real, physical printer using Flash. I want to do this so that typical page headers added by the browser (eg. the URL and "Page x of y") do not get added to the printout.

Perhaps I could generate a PDF and pass it to the SWF, or perhaps I could just send raw HTML ann CSS to the SWF, and then I could call some .print() method via Javascript against the SWF.

So, 1) is this possible? and 2) is there a library (on GitHub perhaps) somewhere that would let me do this?

Comment: What is the added value to use flash for printing a webpage ?

Comment: It could serve as a mechanism to not show page headers injected by the browser: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FWayL.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would [ping a server-side script (php)](http://www.flash-here.com/tutorials/flash_loadvars_sample.html) which would [snap shot](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) the page you want and display the image which flash can then print using flash's [printjob](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/printing/PrintJob.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#includeExamplesSummary) functionality. Hope that helps!

**steps:**

- 1) load the page that will display the url snapshot (snapshot taken
  with php) using a Loader class. Make sure the headers are correct on
  the php page (so browsers think it's an image).
- 2) use the flash
  printjob to print the image

Comment: Just noticed that the snippet example code for that printjob thing is a joke. Wow.

Comment: @Marty hah, yeah. getting your head around printjob is quite the chore.

Comment: I moreso meant that that example is syntactically incorrect / won't compile ie there's functions being called not within the constructor.

Comment: Good information. Is it possible to send a PDF to printjob in place of an image?

Comment: @Chad there probably is, but I don't know it. I know the Loader class only accepts swf, jpg, png, and gif. Maybe you could have PHP make a swf with a pdf inside it, but that might be too much work.