# Taking website screenshots with Flash (or Java), client-side

Tags: java, flash, screenshot, client-side

Is there a way, or is it even possible to take a screenshot of a website with Flash (or Java)? If it is, could someone please provide some basic information on how to achieve this?

The reason why I need it to be Flash or Java (or even Canvas), is because the screenshot needs to be done on the client-side.

I did some research with no definitive answer to my question.

Comment: do you want to take a screenshot of the complete screen or just the content of the browser? complete screen is not possible in flash at least...

Comment: Check out the **answer** to this simliar question about taking a screenshot of a web page from flash: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6901792/is-there-a-way-to-print-a-web-page-via-a-swf/6907433#6907433

Answer (score 0):

From Flash you can not take a screenshot beyond the actual view of the flash rendering area - for security reasons. Just ask the user to press PrintScreen.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the whole PrintScreen matter?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before. Although my solution was to just have javascript send back the actual html rendered on the client-side. I had a servlet that accepts the html code, then the servlet calls an executable (I can't remember what it was, but it was a freeware but has a watermark, it accepts an html in its command-line argument) that produces an image from the html, which the servlet saves to a directory.

Although the business user's requirement also included making sure that the code is not used for spying or snooping on the client side... But they agreed with the outcome of the program in the end. As indeed the screenshot is not made in the client side...